# How to add superscripts to facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I am trying to plot three variables and want the units in the axes labels but can't find a way to label them properly in facets with the superscripts.

I've tried `as_labeller`, `label_bquote`, `expression`/`paste` and changing the original data.

```
p <- ggplot(data = LST, aes(x = Date, y = Measurements)) + 
geom_point((aes(color = parameter)))

p + facet_grid(parameter ~ ., scales = "free_y", 
switch="y",labeller=as_labeller(DO~(mg~L^{-1}), Temperature~(°C), Light~ 
(µmol~m^{-2}~s^{-1}))) + 
            theme_bw()+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), 
legend.title = element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside", 
panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
          scale_x_datetime()+ ylab(NULL) +ggtitle("Spring 2018") + 
scale_colour_manual(values=c('royalblue1', 'springgreen4', 'darkblue')) +
          theme(legend.position="none")+ 
theme(strip.text=element_text(size=10))
```

Everything I try either labels all facets the same or doesn't place the superscripts. I'm pretty new at `ggplot2` so am unsure if what I'm trying will help.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Remove code that's not essential to your question (the colors and text size seem to be just noise here)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `labeller = label_parsed`.  Here's a simple example

```
mt = mtcars

mt$facets = factor(mt$cyl, labels = c(
    "DO~(mg~L^{-1})", 
    "Temperature~('°C')", 
    "Light~(µmol~m^{-2}~s^{-1})"))

ggplot(mt, aes(mpg,cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~facets, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]